# how to select item from readonly input field

Tags: cypress

How do I select a dropdown from input:

```
CypressError: cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <input type="text" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select a ID" name="Id" class="el-input__inner">
```

Currently using:

```
 cy.get('input[name="Id"]').select("ccc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cy.get('input[name="Id"]').select("ccc", { force: true });
```